# funçao para inserir um no numa lista ligada em C

Tags: c, ponteiro, lista-encadeada

Como e que se pode completar o código que falta nas linhas com 1. 2. 3. 4.?

O objectivo é adicionar um novo nó com um determinado nome e idade no fim da lista.

NOTA: sei que há formas menos confusas e mais práticas de resolver isto, e sei resolver o problema de outra forma, mas preciso de saber como resolver com o código estruturado desta maneira.

CODIGO:

```
struct lista {
    char nome[40];
    int idade;
    struct lista * prox;
};

int insere(char * nome, int idade, struct lista ** primeiro) {
    struct lista * no = malloc(sizeof(struct lista)), *atual = *primeiro, *ant = NULL;

    if (no == NULL)
        return 0;
    strcpy(no->nome, nome);
    no->idade = idade;
    no->prox = NULL;

    while (atual != NULL) {
        1.
        2.
    }

    if (ant != NULL)
        3.
    else
        4.
    return 1;
    }

int main(void) {

    int i;
    struct lista pessoas[] = { {"Jose", 18}, {"Rita", 20}, {"Paula", 19}, {"Ezequiel", 15}, {"Alexandre", 25}}, * minhalista, * primeiro;

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(pessoas) / sizeof(pessoas[0]); i++) {
        if (insere(pessoas[i].nome, pessoas[i].idade, &minhalista) == 0)
            printf("Erro ar inserir %s\n", pessoas[i].nome);
    }

    primeiro = minhalista;

    while (primeiro != NULL) {
        printf("%s tem %d anos\n", primeiro->nome, primeiro->idade);
        primeiro = primeiro->prox;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Esse código está muito confuso...... Pretende inserir elemento no inicio da lista ou no final?

Comment: no fim da lista.
este codigo é tirado de um exercicio que me foi dado por um professor, e o enunciado é o seguinte:

Complete a função insere, que insere um nó com um determinado nome e idade no
fim da lista.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O código para as linhas que estão em falta é o seguinte:

```
int insere(char * nome, int idade, struct lista ** primeiro) {
    struct lista * no = malloc(sizeof(struct lista)), *atual = *primeiro, *ant = NULL;

    if (no == NULL)
        return 0;
    strcpy(no->nome, nome);
    no->idade = idade;
    no->prox = NULL;

    while (atual != NULL) {
        ant = atual; //1. 
        atual = atual->prox; //2.
    }

    if (ant != NULL)
        ant->prox = no; //3.
    else
        *primeiro = no; //4.
    return 1;
}
```

Falta no `main` iniciar a lista com `NULL` senão o `while` não irá funcionar corretamente pois o atual(primeiro) nunca é `NULL`:

```
int main(void) {
    struct lista pessoas[] = { {"Jose", 18}, {"Rita", 20}, {"Paula", 19}, {"Ezequiel", 15}, {"Alexandre", 25}}, * minhalista = NULL, * primeiro;
//  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^
```

Explicando as linhas que coloquei:

1. Atualizar o nó anterior para que fique atrás do `atual`
2. Atualizar o nó atual para que fique a apontar para o próximo
3. Quando o `ant` é diferente de `NULL` a lista não está vazia e por isso o novo nó é colocado no fim, a seguir ao `ant` pois o `atual` ficou a apontar para nulo.
4. Quando a lista está vazia o novo nó passa a ser o primeiro da lista.

[Veja a funcionar no ideone](https://ideone.com/3EzvNq)

Comment: Muito obrigado, já percebi como se faz, as linhas 1 e 2 eram como eu pensava, só não sabia resolver a 3 e 4. Mas também não soube identificar o erro no (main). Como no enunciado do exercício vinha desta forma eu não questionei. Ajudou-me bastante, agradeço novamente. :)

Comment: Sem problema, estamos cá para ajudar :)